# Get Key Value on Row from MySQL Database By Using Email Address

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get a value from a Key called Name in the Mysql Database by using the Email Address on the same row of the Name key. I need to echo the value of Name in PHP. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here's what I have: (Credits and thanks Mark Fajardo for this code, I made small modifications)

```
$db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

if(array_search($email, $row) != false) { // this will return false if not found
    $name = $row["name"];
    echo $name;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Right now it only getting the first row in the database.

Thanks for everyone that answered! I feel like I'm getting closer to the getting it working!

Comment: Great! So what have you [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? And where's your code?

Comment: Not sure how to query this type of request.

Comment: Well have you tried *anything*? Or done any research on how to go about doing this? And what did your findings show?

Comment: Yes, that's why I am postiing on here because can't find what I'm looking for, been stuck for days as I'm new to running queries with MySQL. Any help is appreciated. Are you not familiar with MySQL?

Comment: Here's a quick cheat sheet for you. You should look on MSDN how each query type works. https://devhints.io/mysql I strongly suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 and googling any questions or options in the query. You'll need to use a `SELECT`. Stackoverflow isn't here to give you answers without any code showing attempts based on the guidelines. Hope this helps

Comment: Please see updated question. Thanks

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have a database with table fields like :

- id
- email
- name

**So to retrieve these values ​​from the database in PHP you just have to make a request -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php**

For this example, we could think of something like :

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$requete = $myDb -> query('SELECT id, email, name FROM tableName WHERE email=' . $email);
```

**I strongly advise you to use prepared queries to retrieve or display a value entered by the user which is surely the case of 'name'**

And for display it you need :

```
$data = $requete -> fetch();

// ...

echo $data['name'];
```

That's all ! You now know how to recover data from a database :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $result = mysql_query($sql); 

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
         echo $row['name'].'<br>'; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your sql query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$results = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
$name = $results['name'];
```

Or like so

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$results = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);

if(array_search($email, $row) != false) { // this will return false if not found
    $name = $row["name"];
}
```

**Edit**

To get all the rows

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    if(array_search($email, $row) != false) { // this will return false if not found
        $name = $row["name"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I modified the code as it wasn't working initially.
Please see my update in my original post. 

RIght now it's only getting the first row of the database and its not searching for the row where the email is. Please check and thanks for your help!

Comment: To get all the rows, you must make a loop.